# java script is not working in jsp file spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

When I run my jsp files java script is not working, I can't understand why I use jstl tag and I'm putting my jsp file under ressource.Can anyone tell me what's wrong thank you

web.xml

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Dispatcher-servlet

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

JSP file
    ">

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"/>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use JSTL tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```